# SQL select by qualifying multiple strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find student names who are enrolled in a class AND also in another class. But when I do a WHERE statement it cuts out out all the other lines that have the other classes.

So my question is: How would I go about doing it so that it compares the entire group and only selects students that are both in CLASSA and CLASSB.

Some of the students are in CLASSA and some of them are in CLASSB and some are in both. How do I get the one that is in both?

For example:

- John Smith is in CLASSA
- BETTY WHITE is in CLASSB
- Timmy Edwards is in CLASSA
- Timmy Edwards is in CLASSB

If I use an OR, it will select all of the names. But I only want a student that is in BOTH classes. So Timmy Edwards is the one I want selected.

```
WHERE C.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Systems Analysis%'
```

AND C.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Project Management%'

Comment: Can you specify which tables you have and which SQL statement you've already tried?

Comment: Sure, SELECT S.FIRST_NAME||' '||S.LAST_NAME,C.DESCRIPTION
FROM STUDENT S
JOIN ENROLLMENT E
ON (E.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID)
JOIN SECTION SE
ON (SE.SECTION_ID = E.SECTION_ID)
JOIN COURSE C
ON (C.COURSE_NO = SE.COURSE_NO)                                                        So far What i need to do is They have to be in classes Systems Analysis and  Project Management class. So I can search for then individually and with an OR statement. but that still pulls up people that arent in BOTH of them.

Comment: Sorry the formatting is terrible. It looks a lot better on my computer

Comment: But why can't you use AND? I don't know the structure of your database so I can't really help you. Maybe you could post some more info (try to edit your post instead of posting a comment)?

Comment: How does your WHERE statement looks like which you have tried yet?

Comment: Is it correct that the field `C.DESCRIPTION` contains multiple strings (e. g. `System Analysis` and `Project Management`)? How are they separated? Can they apear in any order?

Comment: They are separated by the names. So a way to look at it is as if each name had a class attached to it. So if i printed out all the names the name BOB would appear multiple times for each class he is in

Answer (score 1):

You can do use `group by` and `having`:

```
select student
from enrollments
where class in ('CLASSA', 'CLASSB')
group by student
having count(*) = 2;
```

This version assumes that a student can be enrolled only once for a given class.

Comment: You might want to add `distinct` to remove the inevitable duplication.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I'll have to remember this in the future. I never know when to use Count(*) ever so i'll have to try to force my self to use it more. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacobm001 . . . There is no "inevitable duplication".

Answer (score 0):

No individual row will every have information for both classes. That means that `AND` and `OR` as you're using them are useless. You need to check for the existence of such rows using the `EXISTS` keyword.

```sql
select distinct
  student
from
  enrollments
where
  exists (
    select 
      1 
    from 
      enrollments e1
    where
      e1.student   = enrollments.student
      and e1.class = 'CLASSA'
  ) and exists (
    select 
      1 
    from 
      enrollments e2
    where
      e2.student   = enrollments.student
      and e2.class = 'CLASSB'
  )
```

**Note:**
Each row will have the student name in it, so I've added the `DISTINCT` keyword to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, (although im not sure what exactly your schema is like...)

```
    WITH a AS
    (
        SELECT 
        S.FIRST_NAME||' '||S.LAST_NAME [Student]
        ,C.DESCRIPTION 
        FROM STUDENT S 
        JOIN ENROLLMENT E ON (E.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID) 
        JOIN SECTION SE ON (SE.SECTION_ID = E.SECTION_ID) 
        JOIN COURSE C ON (C.COURSE_NO = SE.COURSE_NO)

        WHERE C.DESCRIPTION  = 'CourseA'
    )
    ,b AS
    (
        SELECT 
        S.FIRST_NAME||' '||S.LAST_NAME [Student]
        ,C.DESCRIPTION 
        FROM STUDENT S 
        JOIN ENROLLMENT E ON (E.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID) 
        JOIN SECTION SE ON (SE.SECTION_ID = E.SECTION_ID) 
        JOIN COURSE C ON (C.COURSE_NO = SE.COURSE_NO)

        WHERE C.DESCRIPTION  = 'CourseB'
    )

    Select a.Student, a.Description [DescA], b.Description [DescB]
    from a join b on a.Student = b.Student

    --optional where to just get students in both classes...
    where a.Description is not null and b.Description is not null
```

Hope this assists...

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the neat trick of joining a SELECT result with itself and then selecting from that result.

```mysql
SELECT A.NAME
FROM (SELECT S.FIRST_NAME||' '||S.LAST_NAME as NAME, 
             S.STUDENT_ID as S_ID,
             C.DESCRIPTION as DESC
        FROM STUDENT S 
        JOIN ENROLLMENT E ON (E.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID) 
        JOIN SECTION SE ON (SE.SECTION_ID = E.SECTION_ID) 
        JOIN COURSE C ON (C.COURSE_NO = SE.COURSE_NO)) A

JOIN (S.STUDENT_ID as S_ID, C.DESCRIPTION as DESC
        FROM STUDENT S 
        JOIN ENROLLMENT E ON (E.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID) 
        JOIN SECTION SE ON (SE.SECTION_ID = E.SECTION_ID) 
        JOIN COURSE C ON (C.COURSE_NO = SE.COURSE_NO)) B   

ON A.S_ID = B.S_ID
WHERE A.DESC LIKE 'Systems Analysis%'
  AND B.DESC LIKE 'Project Management%'
GROUP BY A.NAME
```